# Inserting value to column which is not existing in input using ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ogr2ogr, geopackage

I am inserting geopackage to a table in the PostgreSQL if a certain value is not null with the following comment

```
ogr2ogr -append -nln pgtablename  -f PostgreSQL "PG:host=xx user=xx dbname=xx password=xx"  E:\workspace\DATA_WORK\data\edit\70319.gpkg Bauwerkslinie -sql "SELECT * from Bauwerkslinie where begehung_von IS NOT NULL"
```

It works as expected. In the table `pgtablename`, there is a column that I do not have in gpkg `transactionid` and I would like to insert a value, that will be always the same for the affected objects in the command above.

Any idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to change your SQL from:

```
"SELECT * from Bauwerkslinie where begehung_von IS NOT NULL"
```

to

```
"SELECT *, 99 as transactionid from Bauwerkslinie where begehung_von IS NOT NULL"
```

where "99" is whatever value you want in the new column.

This works for me with a simple geopackage example.

If `transactionid` already exists in your data then select this first, before the star. This does not update `CRESS_ID`:

```
$ ogr2ogr out.gpkg nine.gpkg  -sql "SELECT *, 1001 as CRESS_ID from nine;"
$ ogrinfo -al out.gpkg | grep CRESS
CRESS_ID: Integer (0.0)
  CRESS_ID (Integer) = 86
  CRESS_ID (Integer) = 85
  CRESS_ID (Integer) = 79
  CRESS_ID (Integer) = 99
```

But this does:

```
$ ogr2ogr out.gpkg nine.gpkg  -sql "SELECT 1001 as CRESS_ID,* from nine;"
$ ogrinfo -al out.gpkg | grep CRESS
CRESS_ID: Integer (0.0)
  CRESS_ID (Integer) = 1001
  CRESS_ID (Integer) = 1001
  CRESS_ID (Integer) = 1001
```

The order of columns might be changed *but* the order of columns in a relational table model is not part of the model - nor is the order of rows!

Comment: Beat me to it, @Spacedman. Was just about to say the same thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504163/include-in-select-a-column-that-isnt-actually-in-the-database is a link to using constants as an alias.

Comment: The columns in my gpkg should be in the same order as in the DB?

Comment: @Spacedman If so, I think I should write the all fields name instead *. Because the columns are unfortunately not same order and a couple of colums are existing only in gpkg

Comment: Try it and report the result.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying there's a `transactionid` in your input fields, and you want to set that to (say) "99" in the output field? That's not how I read your question.

Comment: All good! Your suggestion is worked. I just changed it like this `"SELECT fid, field_1, field_2, field_3 , 99 as transactionid from Bauwerkslinie where begehung_von IS NOT NULL"`


`

Comment: @Spacedman sorry I have seen that I wrote wrongly in the previous comment. The fields of my input and output are not identical. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possibly the geopackage might add a `fid` column. Otherwise that looks like a bug. The fields should be identical.